# How to Speed Up Metal Code for iOS/Mac OS

Tags: ios, macos, metal

I'm trying to implement code in Metal that performs a 1D convolution between two vectors with lengths. I've implemented the following which works correctly

```
kernel void convolve(const device float *dataVector [[ buffer(0) ]],
                     const device int& dataSize [[ buffer(1) ]],
                     const device float *filterVector [[ buffer(2) ]],
                     const device int& filterSize [[ buffer(3) ]],
                     device float *outVector [[ buffer(4) ]],
                     uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    int outputSize = dataSize - filterSize + 1;
    for (int i=0;i<outputSize;i++) {
        float sum = 0.0;
        for (int j=0;j<filterSize;j++) {
            sum += dataVector[i+j] * filterVector[j];
        }
        outVector[i] = sum;
    }
}
```

My problem is it takes about 10 times longer to process (computation + data transfer to/from GPU) the same data using Metal than in Swift on a CPU. My question is how do I replace the inner loop with a single vector operation or is there another way to speed up the above code?

Comment: Your kernel function is written in an entirely serial fashion, and doesn't take advantage of the parallelism of the GPU. Before you set about optimizing it, though, how big is your data vector and how often does it change? If the time to transfer the data dominates the time to process it, using the GPU might not be the right approach.

Comment: yes, like @warrenm has already pointed out, you are not taking advantage of the parallelism in GPU. This is not how GPUs do things efficiently. You have to send the data to the GPU so that each fragment calculates the separate range of multiplications.

Comment: GPU example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576976/1d-convolution-without-if-else-statements-non-fft

Comment: @warrenm the data vector is around 10,000 (but may be larger) and the filter size is ~64. My timing tests show that it takes significantly longer to process the data (with the above code) than to transfer the data to/from the GPU.

Comment: @warrenm do you know how to recode the above to process in parallel?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key to taking advantage of the GPU's parallelism in this case is to let it manage the outer loop for you. Instead of invoking the kernel once for the entire data vector, we'll invoke it for each element in the data vector. The kernel function simplifies to this:

```
kernel void convolve(const device float *dataVector [[ buffer(0) ]],
                     const constant int &dataSize [[ buffer(1) ]],
                     const constant float *filterVector [[ buffer(2) ]],
                     const constant int &filterSize [[ buffer(3) ]],
                     device float *outVector [[ buffer(4) ]],
                     uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filterSize; ++i) {
        sum += dataVector[id + i] * filterVector[i];
    }
    outVector[id] = sum;
}
```

In order to dispatch this work, we select a threadgroup size based on the thread execution width recommended by the compute pipeline state. The one tricky thing here is making sure that there's enough padding in the input and output buffers so that we can slightly overrun the actual size of the data. This does cause us to waste a small amount of memory and computation, but saves us the complexity of doing a separate dispatch just to compute the convolution for the elements at the end of the buffer.

```
// We should ensure here that the data buffer and output buffer each have a size that is a multiple of
// the compute pipeline's threadExecutionWidth, by padding the amount we allocate for each of them.
// After execution, we ignore the extraneous elements in the output buffer beyond the first (dataCount - filterCount + 1).

let iterationCount = dataCount - filterCount + 1
let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: min(iterationCount, computePipeline.threadExecutionWidth), height: 1, depth: 1)
let threadgroups = (iterationCount + threadsPerThreadgroup.width - 1) / threadsPerThreadgroup.width
let threadgroupsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: threadgroups, height: 1, depth: 1)

let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()
commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(computePipeline)
commandEncoder.setBuffer(dataBuffer, offset: 0, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&dataCount, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, at: 1)
commandEncoder.setBuffer(filterBuffer, offset: 0, at: 2)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&filterCount, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, at: 3)
commandEncoder.setBuffer(outBuffer, offset: 0, at: 4)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
commandEncoder.endEncoding()
```

In my experiments, this parallelized approach runs **400-1000x faster** than the serial version in the question. I'm curious to hear how it compares to your CPU implementation.

Comment: Your code runs about 450 times faster than my CPU version. This is way faster than I expected. Thank you for such an exceptional answer.

Comment: Hi @warrenm. I am trying to implement what you described, but I cannot create a `MTLBuffer` with `makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy:length:options:deallocator:)`, I get the error message _pointer 0x16fcbbd48 is not 4096 byte aligned_. I tried with an array where the length is a multiple of 4096 and I still get this error... `makeBuffer(bytes:length:options:)` seems to work, but here I don't know how to get the output buffer data back into the float array. @Epsilon if either of you two could post or send me all the boiler plate code I would be extremely grateful...

Comment: @MaxiMus You should post this as a separate question instead of in the comments. Keep in mind, though, that the requirement is that the _pointer_ be page-aligned, not merely that the _length_ be a multiple of the page size. Important distinction.

Comment: OK, thanks. Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770289/allocating-memory-for-data-used-by-mtlbuffer-in-ios-metal

Comment: I ran the experiment myself with data/vector 10'000/64 but only got a speed-up of about 2-3x. Anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong? I'm running it on an iPhone 6s, I don't know if your numbers come from a non-mobile device...

Answer (score -1):

The following code shows how to render encoded commands in parallel on the GPU using the Objective-C Metal API (the threading code above only divides rendering of the output into grid sections for parallel processing; the calculations are still not performed in parallel). It is what you're referring to in your question, even while it's not exactly what you want. I've provided this answer to help anyone who might have stumbled upon this question, thinking that it was going to provide an answer related to parallel rendering (when, in fact, it does not):

```
    - (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view
    {
        dispatch_async(((AppDelegate *)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate).cameraViewQueue, ^{
                    id <CAMetalDrawable> drawable = [view currentDrawable]; //[(CAMetalLayer *)view.layer nextDrawable];
                    MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDesc = [view currentRenderPassDescriptor];
                    renderPassDesc.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
                    renderPassDesc.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
                    renderPassDesc.renderTargetWidth = self.texture.width;
                    renderPassDesc.renderTargetHeight = self.texture.height;
                    renderPassDesc.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture;
                    if (renderPassDesc != nil)
                    {
                        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self._inflight_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
                        id <MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [self.metalContext.commandQueue commandBuffer];
                        [commandBuffer enqueue];
            // START PARALLEL RENDERING OPERATIONS HERE
                        id <MTLParallelRenderCommandEncoder> parallelRCE = [commandBuffer parallelRenderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDesc];
// FIRST PARALLEL RENDERING OPERATION
                        id <MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder = [parallelRCE renderCommandEncoder];

                        [renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState:self.metalContext.renderPipelineState];

                        [renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:self.metalContext.vertexBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];
                        [renderEncoder setVertexBuffer:self.metalContext.uniformBuffer offset:0 atIndex:1];

                        [renderEncoder setFragmentBuffer:self.metalContext.uniformBuffer offset:0 atIndex:0];

                        [renderEncoder setFragmentTexture:self.texture
                                                  atIndex:0];

                        [renderEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangleStrip
                                          vertexStart:0
                                          vertexCount:4
                                        instanceCount:1];

                        [renderEncoder endEncoding];
            // ADD SECOND, THIRD, ETC. PARALLEL RENDERING OPERATION HERE
.
.
.
// SUBMIT ALL RENDERING OPERATIONS IN PARALLEL HERE
                        [parallelRCE endEncoding];

                        __block dispatch_semaphore_t block_sema = self._inflight_semaphore;
                        [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer) {
                            dispatch_semaphore_signal(block_sema);

                        }];

                        if (drawable)
                            [commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];
                        [commandBuffer commit];
                        [commandBuffer waitUntilScheduled];
                    }
        });
    }
```

In the above example, you would duplicate the renderEncoder-related for each calculation you want to perform in parallel. I do not see how this would be of benefit to you in your code example, as one operation appears to be dependent on another. Probably, then, the best you could hope for is the code provided to you by warrenm, even though that doesn't really qualify as parallel rendering, though.

Comment: The OP's question doesn't mention rendering. Parallel render command encoding is a specialized technique that is only useful when command encoding becomes CPU-bound.