# Allocating memory for data used by MTLBuffer in iOS Metal

Tags: ios, c, memory-management, gpgpu, metal

As a follow-up question to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39134325/3119116). I am trying to replace a for-loop running on CPU with a kernel function in Metal to parallelize computation and speed up performance.

My function is basically a convolution. Since I repeatedly receive new data for my input array values (the data stems from a `AVCaptureSession`) it seems that using `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:length:options:deallocator:` is the sensible option for creating the `MTLBuffer` objects. Here is the relevant code:

```
id <MTLBuffer> dataBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:dataVector length:sizeof(dataVector) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared deallocator:nil];
id <MTLBuffer> filterBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:filterVector length:sizeof(filterVector) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared deallocator:nil];
id <MTLBuffer> outBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:outVector length:sizeof(outVector) options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared deallocator:nil];
```

When running this I get the following error:

> failed assertion `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:pointer 0x16fd0bd48 is not 4096 byte aligned.'

Right now, I am not allocating any memory, but (for testing purposes) just creating an empty array of floats of a fixed size and filling it up with random numbers. So my main question is:

**How do I allocate these arrays of floats the correct way so that the following requirement is met**

> This value must result in a page-aligned region of memory.

Also, some additional questions:

- Does it even make sense to create the `MTLBuffer` with the `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy` method, or is copying the data not really an issue in terms of performance? (My actual data will consist of approximately 43'000 float values per video frame.)
- Is `MTLResourceStorageModeShared` the correct choice for `MTLResourceOptions`
- The API reference says

  > The storage allocation of the returned new MTLBuffer object is the same as the pointer input value. The existing memory allocation must be covered by a single VM region, typically allocated with vm_allocate or mmap. Memory allocated by malloc is specifically disallowed.

  Does this apply only to the output buffer, or should the storage allocation for all objects used with `MTLBuffer` not be done with `malloc`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to allocate page-aligned memory is with `posix_memalign`. Here's a complete example of creating a buffer with page-aligned memory:

```
void *data = NULL;
NSUInteger pageSize = getpagesize();
NSUInteger allocationSize = /* required byte count, rounded up to next multiple of page size */ pageSize * 10;
int result = posix_memalign(&data, pageSize, allocationSize);

if (result == noErr && data) {
    id<MTLBuffer> buffer = [device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:data
                                                     length:allocationSize
                                                    options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared
                                                deallocator:^(void *pointer, NSUInteger length)
                                                            {
                                                                free(pointer);
                                                            }];
    NSLog(@"Created buffer of length %d", (int)buffer.length);
}
```

Since you can't ensure that your data will arrive in a page-aligned pointer, you'll probably be better off just allocating a `MTLBuffer` of whatever size can accommodate your data, without using the no-copy variant. If you need to do real-time processing of the data, you should create a pool of buffers and cycle among them instead of waiting for each command buffer to complete. The `Shared` storage mode is correct for these use cases. The caveat related to `malloc` only applies to the no-copy case, since in every other case, Metal allocates the memory for you.

Comment: Hi @warrenm a quick question regarding cycling though buffers. I do want real-time processing of data, however I set `setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES` on my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, so a new frame is never handled before I am finished with all the calculations of the old one, which includes the Metal part. In this case, is it not necessary to create a pool of buffers because I can always use the same ones?

Comment: You wouldn't want to block the capture output's queue on your Metal processing, so you'll be handing work to your Metal command queue to be executed asynchronously. Depending on how long it takes to process a frame, you might have multiple frames in flight at once. If that's the case, you should still use a pool of buffers to avoid read-write conflicts or unnecessary blocking. If you find that you always (or often) complete your processing before the next frame arrives, you could reduce the pool size or even eliminate it altogether.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought discarding late video frames with the method mentioned above does exactly that, i.e. enforce that processing always has to be completed before a next frame is handled, and throw away what arrive early.

Comment: That's true of processing done on the CPU, but there's no reason to block the CPU on the completion of work you've dispatched to the GPU.