# MTLBuffer output values from buffer created with bytesNoCopy (Shared Memory) all Zero

Tags: ios, buffer, shared-memory, metal

I'm calculating a simple convolution on float arrays with a Metal kernel, as described here: [How to Speed Up Metal Code for iOS/Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046347/how-to-speed-up-metal-code-for-ios-mac-os)

My program works, when I set up the MTLBuffers to copy the array data

```
<id>MTLBuffer dataBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytes:dataVector length:sizeof(dataVector) options:0];
```

I can then retrieve the calculated values from the output buffer like this

```
void *output = [outBuffer contents];
for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; ++i) {
    outVector[i] = *(float *)(output + 4 * i);
}
```

I'm now trying to achieve the same goal by creating the MTLBuffers without copying the data, but by sharing the memory, using

```
dataBuffer = [device newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:data length:dataAllocationSize options:MTLResourceStorageModeShared (...)
```

allocating the memory as described here:
[Allocating memory for data used by MTLBuffer in iOS Metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770289/allocating-memory-for-data-used-by-mtlbuffer-in-ios-metal)

However, using the same method to retrieve the output values, I get only floats of value 0.0

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to achieve this. [This](http://memkite.com/blog/2014/12/30/example-of-sharing-memory-between-gpu-and-cpu-with-swift-and-metal-for-ios8/) has a similar setup, they retrieve the values in section 2.5 but I don't understand how to translate from Swift...

**Edit**: So apparently my problem is not reading the data, but filling up the buffer with data in the first place. Essentially I am trying to do the Objective-C version of this

```
var xvector:UnsafeMutablePointer = nil
var alignment:UInt = 0x4000 
var xvectorByteSize:UInt = UInt(maxcount)*UInt(sizeof(Float))
// actual allocation with alignment
posix_memalign(&xvector, alignment, xvectorByteSize)

// pointer handling and casting in Swift..
var xvectorVoidPtr = COpaquePointer(xvector)
var xvectorFloatPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(xvectorVoidPtr)
var xvectorFloatBufferPtr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: xvectorFloatPtr, count: maxcount)

// fill xvector with data
for index in xvectorFloatBufferPtr.startIndex..<xvectorFloatBufferPtr.endIndex {
  xvectorFloatBufferPtr[index] = Float(Index)
}
```

Source: [Memkite](http://memkite.com/blog/2014/12/30/example-of-sharing-memory-between-gpu-and-cpu-with-swift-and-metal-for-ios8/)

.. but I cannot figure out how.

I was doing the following but it's clear now I have to align the memory for the buffer first, and then fill it up with data. What I was doing so far was creating the float array first and then 'pointing' the buffer towards this memory, which obviously is wrong:

```
float dataVector[size];
// Fill it up with random values
void *data = dataVector;
NSUInteger dataAllocationSize = sizeof(dataVector) + pageSize - (sizeof(dataVector) % pageSize); NSLog(@"allocation size %lu", (unsigned long)dataAllocationSize);
int result = posix_memalign(&data, pageSize, dataAllocationSize);
// Create the buffer
```

Comment: Please post your allocation code.

Comment: There's nothing special about buffers created using the copying method versus the non-copying method. If your output data is different, your input data is different. You can confirm that by creating a buffer using each method and comparing their contents without even dispatching any work, then figuring out why they differ.

Comment: You probably aren't allocating the appropriately sized buffer. `dataAllocationSize` is probably the wrong value or `data` is not what you thought it was.

Comment: I edited the question...

Comment: Do you understand how buffer size and alignment works? Size is the maximum amount of space required by a datatype, alignment dictates what byte a datatype can start on. Things with alignment of 4 bytes like packed_float3 can start on every 4 bytes. float3 on every 16 bytes. That is the byte it starts on has to be a multiple of 16. If you start with a type of 4 bytes size, then you need to add 12 bytes of padding before the before you can put something with alignment of 16. This is C struct alignment stuff.